# Php, array_push, add to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add additional entry to an existing multidimensional array using array_push()

Here is my array:
$array =

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Black
            [quantity] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Yellow
            [quantity] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Red
            [quantity] => 30
        )
)
```

What I need now is to add price key after each [quantity], so the final result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Black
            [quantity] => 10
            [price] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Yellow
            [quantity] => 20
            [price] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Red
            [quantity] => 30
            [price] => 0
        )
)
```

`$price['price'][] = 0;`
I have tried using `array_push($price['price'], $array)`

but that doesn't work, it just returns number 2.

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of arrays.  You need to iterate over it to add the price to each sub-array.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $array[$key]['price'] = 0;
}
```

I don't think you want to use `array_push()` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($price as $priceItem) {
$priceItem['price']=0;
$newPrice[]= $priceItem;
}
var_dump($newPrice);
```

Comment: With this way, You have 2 arrays. Not overraid the first one.